# Creating new js file and getting infromation from other js files

Tags: javascript

I have got 2 pages and for every page I have got a separate js file. I wanted to create a new js that would be like a link connecting these two pages together.

On one page I am displaying my objects from the array list:

html:

```
<div id="pop-up" class="hidden">
  <img src="https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-1100x628.jpg" alt="pop">
</div>
  <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="animallist"></div>
```

javascript:

```
const animals = [{
    name: "Cat",
    useful: "no",
    image: "https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png"
  },
  {
    name: "Dog",
    useful: "yes",
    image: "https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-1100x628.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Fish",
    useful: "no",
    image: "https://cdn0.wideopenpets.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Fish-Names-770x405.png"
  },
  ]

animals.forEach(addLink);

function addLink(animal, i) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const animalList = document.createElement('h2');
  const image = document.createElement('img');
  image.id = "image";
  animalList.innerHTML =  animal.name + " " +"-"+"useful?" + " "+ animal.useful;
  animalList.style.cssText = "text-align:center;"
  image.classList.add("highlight");
  image.src = animal.image;
  div.appendChild(image);
  div.appendChild(animalList);
  div.dataset.animalName = animal.name;
  animallist.appendChild(div);
}
```

Some information from the first page is connected to the information on the second page. I wanted to create a function that is triggered by clicking on the `animal.name` and it would redirect me to the second page and put the `animal.name` inside the search box as input value. The problem with that is, I am not sure If I can transfer some information from the js file that is assigned to the first page and transfer is to the new js file (things like index value of the animal) and then pass it to the second page.

Here's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epntw9yv/9/), just for the sake of experiment, can we assume that these 2 pages are identical and I want to redirect to the different url but the page would look identical and the input value would change to the `animal.name`?

Comment: Hi, so you can access any function, variables, constants, classes etc from one js file to another but they should be referenced in the same file and also they should be placed as if you want data from js file a to js file b and place script file js a on top and js b on bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to create a file on the client-side javascript, but you could redirect the user to the second page with a variable in the URL  with

```
location.replace('/second-page?animal=Aminal&&index=0')
```

On the second page you can extract these variables with this code :

```
function getUrlParams(search) {
const hashes = search.slice(search.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&')
const params = {}
hashes.map(hash => {
    const [key, val] = hash.split('=')
    params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val)
})

return params

}

console.log(getUrlParams(window.location.search))
// return a object { animal: 'Aminal', index: 0 }
```

Comment: Ok I got it to work, but there is one problem, the value is entered into input, but It doesn't filter until I press enter. Do you have any idea how to solve it, so it is filtered automatically when I get redirected?

Comment: @menor You could do a [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) eventListener on the input field that does the `location.replace('/second-page?animal=Aminal&&index=0')`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with search parameters in the URL.

Just make a link to `page2?index=[animal index]` and in `page2` use:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("search");
const url = new URL(location);

const animal = animals[url.searchParams.get("index")];
input.value = animal.name;
```